# How to inpaint a region of a picture, with the median of that region?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[This](http://www.eyedocsottawa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ri1.jpg) is the picture I'm working with. I want to select a region (the bright circle in the middle) and inpaint over it with the pixel median of that circle. How do I ago about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`scipy.misc.imread()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) you get an easy to handle array of the picture. Have in mind that each pixel of colored pictures consists of three values, one for each RGB channel. I downscaled the picture to grayscale via `flatten=True` for scalar pixels. Of course you can extend my answer to a separate median of all channels.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
pic = misc.imread("ri1.jpg", flatten=True)
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(pic.shape[1]), np.arange(pic.shape[0]))
circle_x, circle_y, circle_radius = 200, 400, 100
args = np.argwhere( np.sqrt((x-circle_x)**2+(y-circle_y)**2)<circle_radius )
#pic[args] = np.median(pic[args])   # doesn't work?!?
pic[args[:,0], args[:,1]] = np.median(pic[args[:,0], args[:,1]])
misc.imsave("ri1_new.jpg", pic)
```